Default Windows 11 partitions / partitioning scheme
Sometimes you need to partition your disk which already contains a different operating system (OS) or version of Windows thus you use Linux tools such as fdisk or gdisk to create/configure partitions for adding Windows 11. The question becomes which partitions Windows 11 running on UEFI/EFI requires.
Important note: there have been multiple reports recently, that certain Windows updates fail to install because the recovery partition is smaller than Windows needs/expects. I'd recommend allocating at the very least 1GB to it.
This is a follow-up to Default Windows 10 64 EFI partitions / partitioning scheme but now for Windows 11.

@Ramhound I can't replicate what the OP claims, that this is due to Windows Setup (I explain in more detail within my edited answer) and the Win10 v22H2 ISO I downloaded via the Media Creation Tool on 4/5 was last updated 12/2023

@JW0914 - So I am torn. This question isn’t clear nor the original question was clear. I don’t even see an actual question. I think there might be an appropriate question that could be helpful that’s to say, your answer is helpful, but isn’t connected to the right question

@Ramhound From OP's now deleted comments, they're asking what is the default/correct partition layout for Windows 11 because they erroneously believe Windows Setup incorrectly creates the WinRE partition without enough free space, resulting in KB5034441 failing as detailed under Important. OP stated there's numerous forum posts, declining to provide links, and that it occurred to them with a clean install.

@JW0914 - There comments not their question which is the reason the 30+ comments were flagged. I can’t speak if the current Windows image will create a WinRE that’s the correct size or not, but what do know, Microsoft could resize the partition automatically.

@Ramhound I tried twice to replicate the issue the OP mentions and verified the current Win10 v22H2 ISO correctly creates a WinRE partition with enough free space to house the ~5MB increase in winre.wim size from KB5034441, and I show screenshots in my answer of a clean install of Win10 v22H2 while still within the oobeSystem configuration pass, then again once all updates, including KB5034441 have been installed. I'm also unsure why the OP believes the partition layout changes between versions of Windows (per the previous question of the same context for Win10).

@JW0914 - It doesn’t vary and a single answer for both Windows 10 and Windows 11 is appropriate

@Ramhound "...Microsoft could resize the partition automatically" Is that normal outside of the bi-annual version updates, where it's known to occur? My understanding of the version updates are they're applied by Windows Update booting to WinPE and using Windows Setup's offlineServicing, and possibly specialize, passes, during which partitions can be resized and created directly, or via a dynamically generated answer file - normal patch Tuesday updates don't go through the WinPE process AFAIK

@JW0914 - Yes, I would expect it to be done, during the upgrade to a major version update. Windows 10 won’t have another unless Microsoft chooses to say release a rollup update prior to 2025. If they can update WinPE through Windows Update they can increase the size of the partition. I can’t explain why Microsoft hasn’t done that.

Whelp, nice, https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-admits-it-cant-fix-windows-10-kb5034441-0x80070643---errorinstallfailure/
This SE website truly SHINES.


For steps, skip to: Windows' Partition Layout is Standardized Across Versions


Important note: there have been multiple reports recently that certain Windows updates fail to install because the Recovery partition is smaller than Windows needs/expects.


I cannot replicate - in deleted comments, OP claims the cause is Windows Setup

Without OP providing links or screenshots showing Windows Setup incorrectly sizes the WinRE partition during the specialize configuration pass, the only explanation is user error, be it an OEM, custom deployment, or end user 


What the OP describes will occur if a drive has been incorrectly manually partitioned, as by default during the specialize pass, Windows 10 v22H2 creates a 546MB WinRE partition after the OS partition, specifically to avoid this issue:

oobeSystem: 455,474KB [455MB] winre.wim | WinRE partition: 82MB free    KB5034441: 460,232KB [460MB] winre.wim | WinRE partition: 77MB free  
OEMs, and many businesses, bypass Windows Setup's default install.<esd|wim> and unattend.xml (dynamically generated answer file by Setup from user selections), instead deploying Windows manually via a ZTI Deployment Share WIM/FFU through MDT/MEM:

This is a known issue with some deployment partitioned drives, as some OEMs were incorrectly placing WinRE at the front of the drive [WinRE, EFI, MSR, OS] and/or not leaving at least 300MB free for future WinRE updates increasing the size of the winre.wim, which creates this issue since there's no way to resize a WinRE partition at the beginning of a drive because free space is taken from the end of a partition.  If this was to occur during a bi-annual version update, which uses WinPE and Windows Setup, it can shrink the OS partition and create a new WinRE partition either from WinPE directly or during the offlineServicing or specialize passes of Windows Setup, with the new WinRE partition created having the appropriate free space for future size increases; this results in two WinRE partitions and since the original is no longer needed, it can be deleted






Windows' Partition Layout is Standardized Across Versions:

UEFI: (Requires GPT)

EFI: 100MB | Linux Dual-boot: 850MB

Windows requires 100MB and distros require different sizes, with max being ~750MB, so sum both to avoid issues
Only one EFI partition is needed, but if OSes are installed to diferent drives, two are recommended


MSR: 16MB
OS: 64GB minimum (Win <11 varies)
WinRE: 768MB minimum  | 1024MB recommended 


BIOS: (Requires MBR)

Boot: 100MB
OS: 64GB minimum (Win <11 varies)
WinRE: 768MB minimum  | 1024MB recommended 




Manually Configure Partitions in WinPE
To partition a new drive from WinPE, see Steps 1 - 6 at the bottom of this answer

Once Windows Setup's GUI loads, open a terminal: Shift+F10 → DiskPart
::# If storing User Data directories on a partition other than C: (recommended),
::# max size required is ~300GB (multiply size wanted by 1024: 100*1024=102400)

::# List disks:
    lis dis

::# Select OS drive # Windows will be installed to:
    sel dis #

::# List partitions:
    lis par

::# Select and shrink the partition the OS partition [100GB] will be after:
    sel par #
    Shrink Desired=102400 Minimum=102400



Create boot partition:

BIOS:
Cre Par Pri Size=100
Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="Boot"
Active


UEFI:
::# If OS partition is on a drive containing an EFI partition:
    Cre Par Msr Size=16


::# If OS partition is on a drive that doesn't contain an EFI partition:
    Cre Par EFI Size=100
    Format Quick Fs=FAT32 Label="EFI"
    Cre Par Msr Size=16

    ::# If other drive is a drive # before the OS drive, Setup will
    ::# use the other EFI partition; if this occurs:

        ::# Once booted to Windows, mount OS drive's EFI partition
        ::# to Y: via DiskPart, then execute from an Admin terminal:
            BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI

            ::# If Windows doesn't boot with other drive removed, boot WinPE/WinRE:
                BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD





Create OS partition:

Rest of the drive as the OS partition [99GB]:  BIOS:
Cre Par Pri
Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="System"

UEFI:
Cre Par Pri Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="System"


Additional data partitions after the [64GB] OS partition:  BIOS:
Cre Par Pri Size=65536
Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="OS"

UEFI:
Cre Par Pri Size=65536 Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="OS"





Create WinRE partition: (should have 320MB free to allow for future WIM size increases)

BIOS:
Shrink Desired=1024 Minimum=1024
Cre Par Pri id=27
Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="WinRE"


UEFI:
Shrink Desired=1024 Minimum=1024
Cre Par Pri Id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="WinRE"
Gpt Attributes=0x8000000000000001





Close terminal and proceed normally with Windows Setup: exit → exit 


EFI Booting
Prior to booting Windows Setup, ensure within the UEFI firmware settings that:

Secure Boot is always Enabled

Prevents malware injection into the boot process and should be enabled
Distros lacking EFI bootloader signatures:  Add to UEFI signature database via UEFI firmware settings' Boot tab (add. info) 


CSM Mode is always Disabled  Causes UEFI [64bit] to emulate BIOS [16bit] within a 32bit environment

Sole purpose was to enable booting of distros lacking EFI boot circa ≤2017
Motherboard OEMs began phasing out of UEFI firmwares ~2021
Results in substantial performance degradation:

Boot times increase from ~10s to 45s+
MBR is required for the OS drive

MBR max: 4 primary partitions, size of 2TB
GPT max: 128 primary partitions, size of 9.44ZB








What the OP describes will occur if a drive has been incorrectly manually partitioned, as by default during the specialize pass, Windows 10 v22H2 creates a 546MB WinRE partition after the OS partition, specifically to avoid this issue: - this is an abject lie, but whatever: https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-admits-it-cant-fix-windows-10-kb5034441-0x80070643---errorinstallfailure/ On all three PCs where I had this issue Windows was installed fully automatically from the official ISO image without manually partioning anything.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov As was requested before, please provide screenshots verifying that, as I tried to replicate the issue you describe in your question twice and I could not replicate. The screenshots from my attempts to replicate and information regarding that is within the top portion of this answer. KB5034441 only increases the size of the winre.wim by 4,758KB [~5MB].

fdisk
Disk /dev/sda: 55 GiB, 59055800320 bytes, 115343360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D71AA00E-1725-4837-AD44-E6F88C5620F3
First usable LBA: 34
Last usable LBA: 115343326
Alternative LBA: 115343359
Partition entries starting LBA: 2
Allocated partition entries: 128
Partition entries ending LBA: 33

Device         Start       End   Sectors Type-UUID                            UUID                                 Name                         Attrs
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800 C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B 6CDFD4B5-7089-4445-A08B-A6141947B533 Basic data partition         GUID:63
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768 E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE 8EF6E807-2C44-4414-B83B-88B2F1F5BC8B Microsoft reserved partition GUID:63
/dev/sda3     239616 114106367 113866752 EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 F7674BF6-869B-43D5-BEA1-809280529F68 Basic data partition         GUID:63
/dev/sda4  114106368 115339263   1232896 DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC E5A161B4-703A-4CD0-8A65-DA45CD1BFBC4                              RequiredPartition GUID:63



sfdisk
label: gpt
label-id: D71AA00E-1725-4837-AD44-E6F88C5620F3
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors
first-lba: 34
last-lba: 115343326
sector-size: 512

/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=      204800, type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, uuid=6CDFD4B5-7089-4445-A08B-A6141947B533, name="Basic data partition", attrs="GUID:63"
/dev/sda2 : start=      206848, size=       32768, type=E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE, uuid=8EF6E807-2C44-4414-B83B-88B2F1F5BC8B, name="Microsoft reserved partition", attrs="GUID:63"
/dev/sda3 : start=      239616, size=   113866752, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=F7674BF6-869B-43D5-BEA1-809280529F68, name="Basic data partition", attrs="GUID:63"
/dev/sda4 : start=   114106368, size=     1232896, type=DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC, uuid=E5A161B4-703A-4CD0-8A65-DA45CD1BFBC4, attrs="RequiredPartition GUID:63"


gdisk
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 115343360 sectors, 55.0 GiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): D71AA00E-1725-4837-AD44-E6F88C5620F3
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 115343326
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 6077 sectors (3.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          206847   100.0 MiB   EF00  Basic data partition
   2          206848          239615   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   3          239616       114106367   54.3 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   4       114106368       115339263   602.0 MiB   2700

